# Postfix: 550 No Such Domain at this Location

Tags: linux, email, postfix, configuration

I am trying to configure Postfix on a Linux server to only send outbound mail.  I have followed the [null client tutorial](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client) and my Postfix settings are set according to that tutorial.

The email is never sent.  I am trying to send to a gmail address.  The relay shows mail.mydomain.com followed by my mail MX record.  The gmail account is valid.

Can someone please tell me what may need to change in my configuration.  If more details are needed, let me know.

The error message I am concerned with:

`postfix/smtp[16925]: 2536E5B8A: to=<validaddress@gmail.com>, relay=mail.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.32, delays=0.04/0.01/0.12/0.15, dsn=5.0.=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 550 No such domain at this location (in reply to RCPT TO command))`

All of the error messages for completeness:

`postfix/pickup[16383]: 2536E5B8A: uid=33 from=<www-data>

postfix/cleanup[16923]: 2536E5B8A: message-id=<20130321235015.2536E5B8A@removed>

postfix/qmgr[16384]: 2536E5B8A: from=<www-data@domain.com>, size=426, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

postfix/smtp[16925]: 2536E5B8A: to=<validaddress@gmail.com>, relay=mail.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.32, delays=0.04/0.01/0.12/0.15, dsn=5.0.=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 550 No such domain at this location (in reply to RCPT TO command))

postfix/cleanup[16923]: 7763F5B8C: message-id=<20130321235015.7763F5B8C@removed>

postfix/qmgr[16384]: 7763F5B8C: from=<>, size=2505, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

postfix/bounce[16926]: 2536E5B8A: sender non-delivery notification: 7763F5B8C

postfix/qmgr[16384]: 2536E5B8A: removed

postfix/smtp[16925]: 7763F5B8C: to=<www-data@domain.com>, relay=mail.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.26, delays=0.01/0/0.09/0.16, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 550 No such user (www-data@domain.com) (in reply to RCPT TO command))

postfix/qmgr[16384]: 7763F5B8C: removed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems  that:
Postfix at your host tries to use mail.domain.com as smart/relay host
mail.domain.com refuses to relay

It may mean that:
You configured wrong smart/relay host
*OR*
The host requires SMTP AUTH to relay

Comment: OR - they forgot to add their own ip address to the list of clients allowed to relay mail via that server.